# How to add object files in a dir without losing automaticity

Tags: c, bash, makefile

I can't add my object files in a directory; I could do it one by one, I believe, but that would lose the main interest, which is its automaticity.

```make
CC=gcc 
CFLAGS=-Wall -Iinclude
vpath %.c src
vpath %.h include
SRC = src
INCLUDE = include
TARGET=sokoban
TOZIP= $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.c) $(wildcard $(INCLUDE)/*h)
OBJ= game.o main.o
DOCGEN = doxygen
DOCPATH = doc
DOXYFILE = $(DOCPATH)/Doxyfile
LIBNAME=sokobanLibrary.zip
 
 
.PHONY: all doc archive run clean
 
all: build archive doc run
 
build: $(TARGET)
    $(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ -lm
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< 
 
archive:
    zip $(LIBNAME) $(TOZIP)
 
run: $(TARGET)
    ./$(TARGET)

doc:    
    $(DOCGEN) $(DOXYFILE) -o $(DOCPATH)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ) $(TARGET) $(LIBNAME)
    rm -r doc/html
    rm -r doc/latex
```

Comment: Do you mean atomicity? Not automaticity.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean by "add my files in a subdirectory" -- I can think of at least two alternatives, and I am in no way confident that they are the only ones. Nor is it clear what you mean by the very uncommon word "automaticity", or why you think you have it now or why you think it might be at risk.

Comment: I think I meant genericity. In the way that I can add new files and get the executable without too many modifications in my makefile. And by add my files in a subdirectory, I meant that I want to have my .o files in a folder named obj. However the solutions that I found required to do each object file one by one and mv them in a folder. Thus I try to find a correct solution

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your Makefile to achieve this by organizing your source files and object files within separate directories.

Here I have updated  your Makefile:

```
CC=gcc 
CFLAGS=-Wall -Iinclude
vpath %.c src
vpath %.h include
SRC = src
INCLUDE = include
OBJDIR = obj
TARGET=sokoban
TOZIP= $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.c) $(wildcard $(INCLUDE)/*.h)
OBJ= $(patsubst $(SRC)/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(wildcard $(SRC)/*.c))
DOCGEN = doxygen
DOCPATH = doc
DOXYFILE = $(DOCPATH)/Doxyfile
LIBNAME=sokobanLibrary.zip

.PHONY: all doc archive run clean

all: build archive doc run

build: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ -lm

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c | $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)

archive:
    zip $(LIBNAME) $(TOZIP)

run: $(TARGET)
    ./$(TARGET)

doc:
    $(DOCGEN) $(DOXYFILE) -o $(DOCPATH)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR) $(TARGET) $(LIBNAME) doc/html doc/latex
```

This modification introduces a separate obj directory to store the object files. The pattern rule for building object files ensures they are placed in the `obj` directory. The `$(OBJDIR)` target ensures the directory exists.